# Find files/directories recursive in a folder Java

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I want to get all suborders of a certain folder (not only direct suborders but also all sub-suborders etc. --> recursive) that contain a certain regex. This should be as efficient as possible.

The regex is entered by the user. For example he enters "hello" and then all suborders of an folder (`myFolder)`should be listed which contain the regex ".* hello .*". More specific, the paths of the found folders should be returned.

I have already done some research and found nio.file, but I am not sure if nio.file is faster than io.file in this case. Im new to this whole topic, so excuse me if I say something that was not correct.
I use Java 11.

For example, I also found a function like this and it works:

```
Stream s = Files.find(
                Paths.get("myFolder"), 
                Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                (path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
                    File f = path.toFile();
                    return f.getName().matches(".*'myRegexHere'.*") && f.isDirectory() && !f.isHidden();
                });
```

But I'm not sure if there are more efficient functions/approaches or a more efficient way.  I am open for suggestions and ideas.

**EDIT**:

Is there a way to exclude certain folders from the search?

Comment: [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) is part of java.nio. It is a good solution. Dont forget to close your Streams s.

Comment: use RecursiveTask and run it in a ForkJoinPool you could achieve a good result with parallelism

Comment: > Is there a way to exclude certain folders from the search?
you can exclude them in the regex